# How to call new javascript function on success of previous (Form Validations)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have a form that was written by another developer (I'm not really a developer, more designer than coder)... and I'm trying to add validation where the form data is not sent/emailed until the field validations are successful.

I've gotten much of what I would like, but I'm stuck on having the button trigger the validation and THEN calling the function that sends the data.

I kind of need this quickly, so anyone that can actually help ... appreciate it much!

```
<div class="contactForm">
    <form id="contactForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-send="true"/>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" data-send="true" required />
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone* (format: xxx-xxx-xxxx)" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required />
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" data-send="true" required />
    <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="Note" data-send="true"/>
    <input id="sendForm" type="button" value="Send"
            data-template="indextemplate"
            data-handle="contactForm"
            data-script="system/form_email.php"
            data-pending="Your inquiry is being sent..."
                    data-success="Thank you! We will reach out to you as soon as we can!"/>
                            <span class="icon_spin"></span>
            <span class="message"></span>
    </form>
</div>
</div></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=@$prefix;?>js/email.form.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#sendForm').click(function(event) {

    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');

    for(let input of inputs) {
      input.addEventListener('invalid', (event) => {
      input.classList.add('error');    
      }, false);

      input.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
      input.checkValidity();
      })

    }
    on success -> { submitForm(); }
    }

    $('.bullets input[name="contact"]').click(function(){
$('#contactForm input[name="subject"]').val($(this).next().find('.subject').text());
    });

    function sendForm() {
     var edata = {
      handle: $('#sendForm').data('handle'),
      script: $('#sendForm').data('script'),
      success: $('#sendForm').data('success')
     };
     $('#sendForm').addClass('sending');
     $('#message').text($('#sendForm').data('pending'));
     var formdata = new FormData();
     formdata.append('subject', $('input[name="subject"]').val());
     formdata.append('name', $('input[name="name"]').val());
     formdata.append('phone', $('input[name="phone"]').val());
     formdata.append('email', $('input[name="email"]').val());
     formdata.append('note', $('input[name="note"]').val());
     formdata.append('template', $('#sendForm').data('template'));
     emailForm(formdata, edata);
    });
</script>
```

I would like the form to not send/email at all until the required fields are properly completed. It would also be nice for there to be some indication for the user of what is required to submit.

Comment: You are adding the validation event listeners after the button is clicked? I guess you want to do that right after the page loads instead.

Comment: Actually, it seems logical that the validation can't happen until the user enters something in the fields, right? So the button actually should begin the validation and the success of validation should start the sendForm function... right?

Comment: Adding an event listener is about telling the browser how to behave in the future, when event X is happening. This should be done once only, and at the earliest opportunity. The code you have keeps adding new listeners whenever the button is clicked. That doesn't really do any harm here, but it's not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Where is `checkValidity()` defined and what does it look like?

Comment: @Aioros It's not custom: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/d9wk508n/ (I had to change the `type` of the submit button to `"submit"`)

Comment: Yeah, the fiddle is all about the validation, and zero about processing the form submission. To fix that, replace `if (!formIsValid) return false;` with `if (formIsValid) sendForm(); return false;`

Comment: @ChrisG - Thanks! It worked for pieces of what we're going for. For the form validation, it was perfect. Only issue is now I have a send button instead of the send text and my icon isn't spinning or part of the link. Also, the data isn't being  emailed to the user or the client. And it's not picking up the subject line.

I changed the input type back to button so you see how it's supposed to look in context. See the test page:(you'll need to scroll to the form at the bottom of the page: https://volarisliveoak.com/liveoak-full/tester-index.php

Comment: I updated the fiddle, using a dummy `emailForm()` function.

Comment: @ChrisG - Thanks! I found the CSS to get the button back to working and spinning. yay! Everything looks great on the validation side. Now I just need to get it sending correctly, which I have gotten some help with. Thanks again for the assist!